# ¿Como multiplicar los numeros pares y primos de un arreglo, por los pares y primos de otro arreglo y almacenar los resultados en otro arreglo?

Tags: java

Los arreglos deben ser de longitud introducida por el usuario, pero supongamos que tenemos estos dos:

```
arreglouni = {3,2,7,8,1,10,11}
arreglodos = {2,5,7,4,8}

arregloresultado = {}
```

El primer impar del primer arreglo debe multiplicarse por todos los pares del segundo arreglo, y el primer par del primero por todos los pares del segundo arreglo y así sucesivamente hasta acabar con todos los del primer arreglo.

```
Ej: 3 * 2 * 4 * 8
```

3 es el impar del primer arreglo, 2, 4, 8 son los pares del segundo.

El resultado de esta multiplicacion (y de las demas) debe guardarse en un tercer arreglo.

Ya llevo varias horas cuestionándome como hacerlo y nomas no doy.
espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

PD: esto esta planteado para JAVA.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int longuno, longdos, aux = 0;
    System.out.println("Ingrese el tamanio del arreglo uno:");
    longuno = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el tamanio del arreglo dos:");
    longdos = sc.nextInt();

    int[] arreglo_uno = new int[longuno];
    int[] arreglo_dos = new int[longdos];

    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo_uno.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese un valor para el arreglo uno (" + (i + 1) + "/" + longuno + ")");
        arreglo_uno[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo_dos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese un valor para el arreglo dos (" + (i + 1) + "/" + longdos + ")");
        arreglo_dos[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Mostramos el arreglo uno: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo_uno.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arreglo_uno[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Mostramos el arreglo dos: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo_dos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arreglo_dos[i]);
    }


    int[] arreglo_res = new int[longuno * longdos];
    int[] arreglo_aux = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo_uno.length; i++) {
        if (arreglo_uno[i] % 2 == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arreglo_dos.length; j++) {
                if (arreglo_dos[j] % 2 != 0) {
                    //arreglo_res[i] = arreglo_res[i]*(arreglo_uno[i]*arreglo_dos[j]); 
                    arreglo_res[i] *= arreglo_uno[i] * arreglo_dos[j];
                }
            }
            //arreglo_res[i] = aux*arreglo_uno[i];
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo_res.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arreglo_res[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: cual es tu avance? , una vez que tengas cargados tus dos arreglos, recorres el primer arreglo con un for o while y por cada numero recorres con otro for o while todo el segundo arreglo, cumpliendo con las validaciones y operaciones que te piden, saludos

Comment: Hola Bro, ya tengo eso, donde me falla es a la hora de ir multiplicando los numeros, tengo: arreglo_res[i] *= arreglo_uno[i]*arreglo_dos[j];

Pero simpre me arroja un cero, jamas multiplica nada, ya que arreglo_res vale cero de forma inicial, pero ya de ahi nose como ir guardando los valores.

Comment: es porque  con *= estas agregando al valor anterior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recorres el primer arreglo con un `for` y por cada numero recorres con otro `for` todo el segundo arreglo, cumpliendo con las validaciones y operaciones que te piden. Algo asi:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arreglo_uno.length; i++) {
    int m = 1; // inicias con 1 (propiedad de la multiplicacion x1 mismo numero)
    if (arreglo_uno[i] % 2 == 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arreglo_dos.length; j++) {
            if (arreglo_dos[j] % 2 != 0) {
                //arreglo_res[i] = arreglo_res[i]*(arreglo_uno[i]*arreglo_dos[j]); 
                m *= arreglo_uno[i] * arreglo_dos[j];
            }
        }
        arreglo_res[i] = m;
    }

}
```

Comment: okey bro, pero como voy manteniendo los valores de la multiplicacion?

Comment: vas manteniendo en otra variable tipo int, y cuando termines de recorrer la segunda lista, simplemente lo guardas en tu arreglo_res. Voy a ir modificado mi respuesta hasta llegar a lo que buscas

Comment: Valeeee! gracias bro!

Comment: De nada amigo, ánimo con la programacion, saludos